# Create Batch File to enable PS script exec and launch elevated PS shell with line commands

Tags: powershell, batch-file, uac

To simplify my job of finding every installer and manually launching them one by one, I would like to make a .bat file that runs a chocolatey install for ~10 app-installers without doing something in the meantime.

I tried to use the `-command` option for entering my command, but it never executed it in a elevated window of PowerShell.

- start bat file --> starts elev PS shell.
- run PS script on Desktop as Admin --> install chocolatey programs.

My code that I would like to run in a elevated PS shell:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -scope Process -Force
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Black -BackgroundColor White "Chocolatey wird heruntergeladen und installiert"
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://community.chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
choco feature enable -n=allowGlobalConfirmation
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Black -BackgroundColor White "Programme werden heruntergeladen und installiert"
choco install googlechrome
choco install firefox
choco install irfanview
choco install mpc-hc-clsid2
choco install 7zip
choco install notepadplusplus.install
choco install vlc
choco install adobereader
choco install libreoffice-still
```

Ideally I just have to click on the .bat file and accept UAC for the admin window of PS and all programs are downloaded and installed in the background.

```bash
powershell -Command "&{ Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList '-File C:\users\gabri\desktop\start.ps1' -Verb RunAs}"
```

The .bat file only shows a UAC, and then nothing happens.

Comment: As an aside: There's no reason to use `"& { ... }"` in order to invoke code passed to PowerShell's CLI via the `-Command` (`-c`) parameter - just use `"..."` directly. Older versions of the [CLI documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) erroneously suggested that `& { ... }` is required, but this has since been corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting `Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -scope Process -Force` *inside a script file* (`*.ps1`) somewhat defeats the purpose, because if the persistently configured [execution policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Execution_Policies) prevents execution of your script to begin with, your attempt at a process-level override never gets to execute.

Instead, use the PowerShell [*CLI*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe)'s `-ExecutionPolicy` parameter for a process-level override of the execution policy.

Additionally, you may want to use the `-NoExit` CLI parameter so as to keep the elevated session open, which allows you to inspect the results.

```bash
:: From a batch file.
powershell -Command "Start-Process -Verb RunAs powershell -ArgumentList '-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoExit -File C:\users\gabri\desktop\start.ps1'"
```